# Clearing array adaptor resources in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

I've got a GridView on an activity and I'm setting a custom font in the constructor for the ArrayAdaptor like this

```
typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf");
```

This seems fine and shows just one occurance of it when issuing

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.example.app
```

If I then exit the activity and go into it again there's then two references to the font resource and so on for every time I enter it.

In what way should I be clearing up that. I can't think where that clear up process should go to release the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `Typeface.createFromAsset` in every activity you might want to create it once in the main app and use it to set font any time you want:

```
textView.setTypeface(mainApp.getTypeface());
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done something similar to this with a static instance.